# How can I export a rails model to json schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-plugins, jsonschema

I am looking to optimize how we build forms for some of our models and ideally I would like to build them from json-schema.

Is there a gem or the like which would allow me to export a model definition to json-schema?

Bonus: With validations.

Bonus: While modelling association relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formtastic: http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic has a mechanism for building forms from the models. Maybe you could base your code on theirs.

Check in lib/formtastic.rb line 474 or so.

Railscast for formtastic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1

Comment: This seems as good as it gets for the moment.. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a gem that creates models based on a JSON Schema: [jsonmodel](https://github.com/Papipo/jsonmodel)

And I am also working on support for formtastic in a separate gem: [jsonmodel-formtastic](https://github.com/Papipo/jsonmodel-formtastic)

Please note that both are a work in progress, but it would be nice to get feedback :-)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about a gem that does this, but you could either pull the SQL or Rails schema data and then parse it, even easier if you're working with thw rails schema, as you can parse it by running it in a Ruby DSL.

Comment: Nod, it certainly seems doable, which is why I was hoping someone had already done it ;)